# Subquery returns thousand of rows, cause slow

Tags: mysql

Having troubles making a subquery like this:

```
SELECT ser_id FROM service 
WHERE ser_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT ser_id FROM history WHERE his_status=2)
```

It has a delay like 4 seconds.

If I run only the subquery:

```
SELECT ser_id FROM history WHERE his_status=2
```

It works in only 0.5 seconds.
This subquery has like 50 thousand of records.

Any way to optimize this? Thank you.

Comment: Having indexes on `ser_id` and `his_status` would help.  Perhaps `not exists` or `outer join / null` would be faster -- in general, with performance related questions, it just depends.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `NOT EXISTS` instead. This should speed up your query when dealing with "large" amount of rows picked within the subquery itself:

```
SELECT s.ser_id
FROM service s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM history h
  WHERE h.his_status = 2
    AND h.ser_id = s.ser_id
  )
```

Try `EXPLAIN` plan though to see the real difference.

Answer (score 0):

First you must create indexes.

```
CREATE INDEX ser_id__index ON service (ser_id);
CREATE INDEX his_status__index ON history (his_status);
```

Then compare these 2 sql

First

```
SELECT ser_id FROM service 
WHERE ser_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT ser_id FROM history WHERE his_status=2);
```

Second

```
SELECT ser_id FROM service 
WHERE ser_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ser_id FROM history WHERE his_status=2);
```